# How to create Api Token for auth PHP

Tags: php, api, authentication, oauth, access-token

I have a rest API in here, then I would like to add the secret password ( token ). where i use to restrict, so that all people can't access it.

this my api code :

```html
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$command = $_GET['command'];
switch ($command) {
// Case update Profile Driver //
    case 'update_driver':
        $result = array();
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "no_password";
        $dbname = "testing_api";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
        if(empty($_POST['id'])){
            $result['api_status'] = 0;
            $result['message'] = 'error';
        }else{
            $result['api_status'] = 1;
            $result['message'] = 'Success';
        }
        echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
        $conn->close();
    break;
```

then, have someone help me to improve my code, so that is work like what i want ?
I would be grateful if anyone can help me to make the authentication is in the authorization with type OAuth 1.0
[image: here]

Comment: Before implementing API Key, you should address a couple of severe security issues with your code. 1. **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. **You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: What happened now? The code is totally different than the original post?

Comment: sorry i change it, iam have a two type (mysql and Mysqli), but i have same problem. how i can make a authentication. how i can token for accessing the data.